# Asynchronous GRPC?

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, grpc, synchronous

I am working on designing a new system that will take a an array of hashes of car data and then use this data to call a separate API that returns a Boolean, after which I will return to the original caller the car model and either true or false.

The system needs to be callable from other applications so I am looking into GRPC to solve the problem. My question revolves around how to implement this solution in GRPC and whether or not something like RabbitMQ would be better?

Would it make sense to make a bidirectional streaming GRPC solution where the client streams in the list of cars and then on the servers end I spawn off say a delayed job for each request on the server? And then when each delayed job finishes processing I return that value to the original caller in a stream?

Is this an elegant solution or are there better ways to achieve my goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The streaming system of gRPC is typically designed for asynchronous communication, so it should fit your usage case neatly.

The general design philosophy in this case is to consider each individual message sent in the stream as independent. Basically, make sure your proto message contains all the information it needs to be parsed and processed by your application without needing any context from previous calls.

Comment: Even in the streams though isn't the call still "synchronous" since each proto message is being sent one by one, and the client is waiting for the full response to end?

Comment: That's not how bidirectional streaming works, no. You get data when it arrives, without a bistable system like you're describing. In fact, the whole of grpc is designed around being asynchronous. The various synchronous functions are in fact just piggybacking on the async versions, and waiting.

Comment: Also in my server file I can get things to work unless making a query to an active record table, how can I call a method in a file in my ruby backend from the grpc server that updates tables in my backend through active record? The file also does http requests.